# Plotting a series of 2D black and white plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot a series of 2D matrices containing ones and zeros (effectively black and white images) in MATLAB, which are ordered in 3D.

The code I have so far is:

```
function PlotthreeD()

 numrows = 100;
 numcols = 100;

 Plot1 = zeros(numcols);
 Plot1(20:50,20:50) = 1;

 Plot2 = zeros(numcols);
 Plot1(20:70,20:90) = 1;

 Plot3 = zeros(numcols);
 Plot3(20:50,20:50) = 1;

         B = cat(3, Plot1, Plot2, Plot3);

 figure; 
 offset = 100;
 hold on; 

 for i=1:3; 
     mesh(B(:,:,i)+offset*(i));
 end

end
```

Is there a drawing command (rather than mesh) that will allow me show the 2D arrays as solid shapes (where the matrix elements equal 1), rather than having a these regions shown as being raised (as they are with mesh)?

Comment: Typo in the second line of this:
    Plot2 = zeros(numcols);
    Plot1(20:70,20:90) = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
numrows = 100;
numcols = 100;
close all;

Plot1 = zeros(numcols);
Plot1(20:50,20:50) = 1;

Plot2 = zeros(numcols);
Plot2(20:70,20:90) = 1;

Plot3 = zeros(numcols);
Plot3(20:50,20:50) = 1;

B = cat(3, Plot1, Plot2, Plot3);
B(B==0)=NaN;

figure;
offset = 100;
hold on;

for i=1:3;
    surf(B(:,:,i)+offset*(i)); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the Matlab function imagesc()

Answer (score 0):

The function [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) is one option. The one thing you would have to be mindful of is this comment in the documentation:

> The default `shading` is `faceted`,
>   which colors each cell with a single
>   color. The last row and column of C
>   are not used in this case.

So you may want to add an extra row and column of zeroes to your matrix by adding 1 to `numrows` and `numcols`.

Here's some sample code from the documentation:

```
pcolor(hadamard(20))
colormap(gray(2))
axis ij
axis square
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SPY is also a good way of viewing binary matrices.